# Bonded ground, other line reading is 0 volts

Tags: power-grid

Can someone explain this data to me:

All machines connected to the grid are normal.

- Line 1 to line 2 = 230 volts
- Line 2 to line 3 = 230 volts
- Line 3 to line 1 = 230 volts
- Line 1 to ground = 230 volts
- **Line 2 to ground = 0 volts**
- Line 3 to ground =  230 volts

Comment: what do you not understand? ... line 2 is bonded to ground

Comment: @jsotola That still doesn't explain line 3 to line 1 being 230V instead of 400V, if it's a 3-phase system.

Comment: Benjamin, please look at your question in edit window, and see how new lines are formed. Although you had written it properly, it looked like a mess in the end because you need to either include <br> at the end of a line, include a number or a dash in front of multiple lines of detail, or hit "Enter" twice to move to a new paragraph.

Comment: …or follow the post editor help and append two spaces to the line *before* the newline.

Comment: Looks like "ground" is connected to phase 2 and not to PE. Possibly through a capacitor. Does "ground" have continuity to a known earth connection?

Answer (score 3):

It's known as a Corner-Grounded Delta (Grounded B Phase) system.

[image]

Corner-grounded delta systems are not recommended for new installations.

However, some utilities still provide this system, and many old installations still exist.